# How to set dates and days automatically of the whole month in 1 to 30 (31, as per the month) cells in google script editior?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the image showing dates and days of december. I need to autobackup a sheet on the 1st date of every month, but in backup sheet created month and days should change to current ones. As in the image its december next month on the execution of trigger it should change 1 to 31 dates of january with days too in the next column as shown. (As per the month it should set dates till 30 or 31 , or 28 for feb). My backup sheet creation part is working fine just i would like to know how to set this dates and days thing.

[image]

Comment: @carlesgg97  Kindly check

Answer (score 3):

**Create This Month Sheet**

The code:

```
function createThisMonth() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shn=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone() ,"MMM-yyyy");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(shn);
  if(!sh) {
    var sh=ss.insertSheet(shn,0);
  }
  var dA=[];
  var cA=[];
  var days=parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new  Date().getMonth()+1,0), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d"));
  for(var d=1;d<=days;d++) {
    var c1=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),d),Session.getScriptTimeZone() , "d-MMM-yyyy");
    var c2=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),d),Session.getScriptTimeZone() , "E");
    var c9=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),d),Session.getScriptTimeZone() , "HH:mm:ss");
    dA.push([c1,c2,0,0,0,0,0,0,c9,'']);
    cA.push(['#ffffff','#ffffff','#ffff00','#ffff00','#ffff00','#ffff00','#ffff00','#ffff00','#00ff00','#ff0000']);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,dA.length,dA[0].length).setValues(dA);
  sh.getRange(1,1,dA.length,dA[0].length).setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

Run this to create trigger:

```
function createTriggerForcreateTheMonth() {
  if(!isTrigger('createThisMonth')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('createThisMonth').timeBased().onMonthDay(1).atHour(1).create();
  }
}
```

Helper function:

```
function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

The Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Used the code, but in out out only 1st decembeer, single row coming

Comment: I made a small change.  It was working yesterday because it was date dependent.  Sorry for the mistake.  I believe it's working correctly now,

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) and [`.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) to generate the dates. So long as your script is clearing just the contents and not also formatting, there should be no need to do any additional formatting within the script (such as [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)).

**Note:** This function returns a 1-dimensional array. To print using [`.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)), you need to pass it a 2-D array.

```
/**
 * Get all of the dates in a particular month. If no month specified, will return dates for the current month.
 * @param {Date} [targetDate] - (Optional) Any date in the desired month
 * @returns {Object[]} - An array of dates for the specified month
 */
function getMonthDates(targetDate) {
  if (targetDate == null) { targetDate = new Date(); } // If none, use today
  targetDate = new Date(targetDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)); // Set target date to midnight for cleaner printing
  var month = targetDate.getMonth(); // Target date's month
  var day = 1; // Always start with the first day of the month
  var dates = []; // Final dates will all be saved here
  var tempDate = new Date(targetDate); // This date will be modified, since .setDate() changes the Date object
  while (day <= 31) { // There can never be more than 31 days
    var date = new Date(tempDate.setDate(day)); // Create a new date with the day variable
    day++; // Increment the day
    if (date.getMonth() == month) { // If new date is within the same month
      dates.push(date); // Add date to dates array
    }
  }
  return dates;
}
```

Specifically, `.setDate()` will automatically increment the month once you go beyond the number of days in a particular month.

```
var date = new Date("2019-11-29"); // November 29, 2019
date.setDate(30); // November 30, 2019
date.setDate(31); // December 1, 2019
```

Using `.getMonth()`, you can check if the incremented date is within the same month. (Keep in mind here that the months are zero-based, so January is the 0th month.)

```
var date = new Date("2019-11-30"); // November 30, 2019
Logger.log(date.getMonth()); // 10
date.setDate(31); // December 1, 2019
Logger.log(date.getMonth()); // 11
```

If your [spreadsheet time zone](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515) and your apps script time zone (File > Project properties) don't match, you may run into issues. There are multiple ways to resolve those issues, but given that it's unlikely you'll have a mismatch, I'll leave that out of this response.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using formula templates inside Apps Script. Note that the script doesn't leave any formulas in cells.
The built-in DAYS function does most of the heavy lifting and allows you to calculate the number of days between the two dates without JS loops and redundant code. 
The SEQUENCE formula is basically a for loop that allows you to fill down dates starting from the first day of the month by incrementing them by 1. The number of increments is always equal to a number of dates in a given month (as of 'today').

See the full working example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VFPpgegPeDNzDUdyx63HCxngNVpfIuBXjjCtPORExlE/edit?usp=sharing). Refer to the 'formula' sheet to see how these formulas work outside the script.

```
 var CONFIG = {
  DATE_FORMAT: "d-mmm-yyyy",
  DATE_FORMULA: "SEQUENCE(DAYS(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0),EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)),1,TODAY(),1)",
  WEEKDAYS_FORMULA: 'ArrayFormula(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY({{range}},1),"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"))'
};

function copyDate() {

  //Get the target sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tSheet = ss.getSheetByName("script_output_sheet");

  //Get first cell of the date range
  var dateCell = tSheet.getRange(1, 1);

  //Copy formula to the date range and fill it up with dates
  dateCell.setFormula(CONFIG.DATE_FORMULA);

  //Get the range of the dates column based on the pasted values
  var dateRange = tSheet.getRange(dateCell.getRow(), dateCell.getColumn(), tSheet.getLastRow(), 1);

  //Add range parameter to the WEEKDAYS_FORMULA
  var weekdaysFormula = CONFIG.WEEKDAYS_FORMULA.replace("{{range}}", dateRange.getA1Notation());

  //Get the first cell for the week days range by offsetting the date cell one column to the right
  var weekdaysCell = dateCell.offset(0, 1).setFormula(weekdaysFormula);

  //Apply proper formatting to the date column
  dateRange.setNumberFormat(CONFIG.DATE_FORMAT);

  //Clean up - remove formulas and paste values only
  var values = tSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  tSheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);




}
```